# How to bind data dynamically into leftTime in ngx-countdown

Tags: typescript, countdown, angular9

I'm using ngx-countdown npm package to show a countdown on my webpage.
I want to set the leftTime attribute according to data coming from the backend, I tried below way, but it does not work,

in my html,

`<countdown #cd [config]="notifyConfig" (event)="handleEvent($event)"></countdown>`

in my component.ts

`notifyConfig: CountdownConfig = { leftTime: this.consultationDurationInSeconds, notify: [120], format: 'mm:ss', };`

`this.consultationDurationInSeconds = data.ConsultationDuration.Minutes*60;`

My data object has the minute which I want to bind to leftTime attribute. but when I try this way it shows an error saying,

** Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date **,

can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution,

I declared below items top of the class,

`consultationDurationInSeconds: any;`

`notifyConfig = { leftTime: this.consultationDurationInSeconds, notify: [120], format: 'mm:ss' };`

And within the function which I getting data,

```
this.consultationDuration = data.ConsultationDuration.Minutes * 60;

this.notifyConfig = { leftTime: this.consultationDuration, notify: [120], format: 'mm:ss' };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

first declare an string containing the time you want,

```
let TimeString = "20:00";

  startCountDown() {
    if (this.timer > 0) {
      this.TimeString = this.getFormattedTime();
      this.timer--;
    }
  }

  getFormattedTime() {
    const duration = moment.duration(this.timer, 'seconds');
    const resultstring = moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('mm:ss');

    return resultstring;
  }
```

You just want to call the startCountDown() function.