# Convert String UTC Date to number for ngx-countdown leftTime config value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm calling a C# API that's returning the following types to my Angular application.

```
export interface Auction {
      reservePrice: number        
      currentHighBid: number    
      auctionEnd: string   
      id: string         
}
```

I created an AuctionListComponent that will `ngFor` a list of auction to the screen and in the list I want to add a countdown timers. So I created another component for that called TimerComponent. The parent component is passing a UTC string date to the child. The child timer component needs a type of number for the ngx-countdown timer to work. I'm no pro at Angular so am I missing something simple here?

I've also looked over this similar questions as well and didn't help me.
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986946/how-to-bind-data-dynamically-into-lefttime-in-ngx-countdown)

[Link to nxg-countdown page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-countdown/v/16.0.0?activeTab=readme)

(Parent) AuctionListComponent.html

```
        <div class="m-3" *ngFor="let auction of auctions">

         <p class="card-text">
              End Date: {{ auction.auctionEnd | date }}    
         </p>                   
                                                        
          <app-timer [childTimer]="auction.auctionEnd"></app-timer>                             
            
        </div>
```

(Child) TimerComponent.html

```
   <p>
    From the parent: <b>{{ childTimer | date : 'MM d, y, h:mm:ss a' }}</b>  
    UTC: <b>{{ childTimer }}</b>    
    </p>

    <p>ngx-countdown Counter</p>

    <countdown [config]="config"> </countdown>
```

TimerComponent.TS

```
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { CountdownConfig, CountdownEvent } from 'ngx-countdown';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrl: './timer.component.scss'
 })
export class TimerComponent {

   @Input() childTimer: string = ''; //This doesn't work because it's the wrong type
   @Input() childTimer: any; //This compiles and give an error
                             //ERROR Error: Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date

   config: CountdownConfig = { leftTime: this.childTimer, format: 'd:H:M:ss'};

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngx-countdown` expects `leftTime` to be a number representing seconds left. So to make it work you need to find a difference between `auctionEnd` which is a UTC string and the current Date and convert it into seconds.

Here is how your component could do this:

```
export class TimerComponent {

 config: CountdownConfig = {
   leftTime: 0, 
   format: 'd:H:M:ss'
 };

 // Turn this into a setter so it updates the config if input changes
 // make sure you use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush to avoid redundant updates
 // or change this as you wish
 @Input() set childTimer(utcDate: string) {
   this.config = {
     ...this.config,
     leftTime: this.calculateSecondsLeft(utcDate)
   };
 }

 private calculateSecondsLeft(utcDate: string): number {
   // Both `parse` and `now` return a timestamp
   const diff = Date.parse(utcDate) - Date.now();
   return diff / 1000;
 }

}
```

---

**Update**

I digged into documentation of `ngx-countdown` and there is `stopTime` option in the config that makes it even simpler as it accepts "end time" as timestamp, so the example could be simplified to:

```
export class TimerComponent {

 config: CountdownConfig = {
   format: 'd:H:M:ss'
 };

 @Input() set childTimer(utcDate: string) {
   this.config = {
     ...this.config,
     stopTime: Date.parse(utcDate)
   };
 }

}
```

---

Regarding `d` in a format showing 1 when `timeLeft` > 24h. It seems that the library uses formatting for Date, while the data is more like `Duration`. When a `diff` is calculated it is a date relative to `Jan 1 1970` and `d` is a "day of month" so it shows `1`. It is better explained [here](https://github.com/cipchk/ngx-countdown/issues/49#issuecomment-547019133). As we cannot subtract 1 day from `Jan 1 1970` there is no easy fix for it that could handle leap days and other Date related edge cases.

Here is an example of how you can add a custom formatter via `formatDate` configuration, and `intervalToDuration` from `date-fns` library:

```
config: CountdownConfig = {
  formatDate: ({ date }) => {
    const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = intervalToDuration({
      start: 0,
      end: date
    });
    return `${days ?? 0}:${hours ?? 0}:${minutes ?? 0}:${seconds ?? 0}`;
  },
};
```

Comment: So when I set my code to what you have above. The `leftTime: this.calcSecLeft` has an error stating: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: Oh, I left wrong initial value there, and there was no type for it, try to start with 0 as leftTime, I updated the answer

Comment: both answers works great! I'm just a wondering why when the counter gets a date that has already happen it shows: `1:0:1:00` and not `0:0:0:00`. Have any idea? guessing 1:0:1:00 is Jan 1 1970.

Comment: @whisk the library does not handle it well, unfortunately, I updated the answer with some info including a link to related issue and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ngx-countdown documentation, the leftTime parameter must be a number.

So if you convert childTimer to number, by instantiating the config variable, it should work correctly.

Comment: Can you give an example?